# Swift 3 capitalize string

Tags: swift, string

```
    let first = postalText.text?[(postalText.text?.startIndex)!]
    let second = postalText.text?[(postalText.text?.index((postalText.text?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: 1))!]
    let third = postalText.text?[(postalText.text?.index((postalText.text?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: 2))!]
```

I'm trying to capitalize the FIRST and THIRD character and then merge all 3 into a new string
but the .uppercase and .capitalized doesn't work .

Also how do i check that the SECOND character is a number ?

Comment: You should post the original String and the desired result

Comment: Btw you need to initialize a String with the characters to be able to use capitalized or uppercase String methods

Comment: `let first = String(postalText.text![postalText.text!.startIndex]).uppercased()`

Comment: Or just provide a range instead of a single index `let firstUppercased = postalText.text![postalText.text!.startIndex...postalText.text!.startIndex].uppercased()`

Answer (score 5):

`.uppercased` and `.capitalized` only work for strings, what you show there are `Character`s. You can cast a `Character` as a `String` and make it capitalized.

```
let firstCapitalized = String(first!).capitalized
```

If you want to check if a `Character` is an int, you can also make it a `String`, and then check if casting the `String` as an `Int` is non-nil:

```
if Int("\(second!)") != nil {
    print("Is Integer")
}
```

These cases all assume your first, second, and third are all non-nil, and force-unwraps them.

**EDIT**
I had some free time and was overlooking some old posts on SO, and I realized this answer I posted isn't using the best coding form. First off, force unwrapping anything is always a bad idea (it's a recipe for a crash in the future), so for the first part. Do something like this:

```
let firstCapitalized = String(first ?? "").capitalized
```

This at least gives you a back-out in case `first == nil` then you'll just be stuck with an empty string.

For the second part, I would use optional unwrapping instead of `if Int("\(second!)") != nil`. I would say the more proper method would be something like this:

```
if let second = second, let stringConvertedToInteger = Int("\(String(second))") {
    print("\(stringConvertedToInteger) is an integer")
} else {
    print("Either second is nil, or it cannot be converted to an integer")
}
```

This will optionally unwrap the character `second`, and if it has a value, convert it to an integer (should it be one, checked by optional unwrapping). This is the safest way to do it, and will keep you from experiencing any runtime errors.

Comment: @LeoDabus - I guess I never realized there was a difference